# What is the purpose of 'let' keyword in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

We can write the code with or without `let` as follows.

```
var str = "Hello World"
str.let { println("$it!!") }
```

OR

```
var str = "Hello World"
println("$str!!")
```

What is the Actual use of `let`?.Is that more memory efficient or more readable?

Comment: This should help: [link](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/1*pLNnrvgvmG6Mdi0Yw3mdPQ.png)

Comment: 1. `str` should be a `val` and 2. there is no benefit to using `let` in this example

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`let` is one of Kotlin's [Scope](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html) functions which allow you to execute a code block within the context of an object. In this case the context object is `str`. There are five of them: `let`, `run`, `with`, `apply`, and `also`. Their usages range from but are not exclusive to initialization and mapping.

They are all very similar but they differ in terms of how the context object is referenced and the value that is returned. In the case of `let` the context object is referenced by the `it` keyword as opposed to the `this` keyword. The return value is whatever is returned from the lambda code block. Other scope functions like `apply` will return the context object instead.

Because `let` returns whatever the lambda block evaluates to, it is most suited to performing a mapping of some kind:

```
var upperStr = str.let { it.toUpperCase()}
```

[apply](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) is a more suited function for what you are doing.

To answer your question as to which code is more preferable, it really depends on what you are using the scope function for. In the above case there is no reason to use `let`. If you are using IntelliJ it will give a warning saying the call to `let` is redundant. Readability here is a matter of preference, and may be preferred.

The `let` function is useful when you wish to perform a null safe operation on an Object by using the the `safe call` operator `?.` When doing this the `let` code block will only be executed if the object is not null. Another reason to use let is if you need to introduce new variables for the operation but you want to confine them to the scope of the let block. This is true for all scope functions, so I reiterate that `let` is best used for a mapping operation.

Edit: The `let` function should incur no additional cost. Normally we would expect the lambda/Code-block to be compiled to a `Function` object but this is not the case for an `inline` function in Kotlin for which the compiler will emit code not dissimilar to the second code example you have given. See the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) for more information.

Answer (score 48):

One of usages you can check nullable types

```
var str: String? = null
str?.let { println("$it!!") }
```

it's equal

```
if (str != null) {
   System.out.println(str);
}
```

in Java, but shorter and more useful

Comment: Shame that `?.let {} ?: ` is not equivalent to `if(!=null) else {}` so you might want to use the `let` only in actual assignments and not all over the code

Comment: @EpicPandaForce but `if(!=null) else {}` could also be written as something like `?.let { /* if != null content */ } ?: run { /* else content */ }`... or did you mean something else?

Comment: @Roland Exactly, but the two statements are actually not equivalent. So people should generally not use this `?: run {` stuff at all unless they are 100% sure they know what they are doing. Otherwise, use `if else`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce depends on how you use it, right? if we skip "equivalent" for a moment (because under the hood they are really more different) at least we can say that the following will lead to the same result: `val x = if (y != null) y+1 else z` is similar to `val x = y?.let { it + 1 } ?: run { z }` ... with the latter being a bit safer in case that `y` is mutable and altered in another thread...

Comment: I wouldn't say the kotlin version is shorter or more useful. IMO the kotlin is has higher cognitive load ... which is the opposite of a good thing. The java is a test, a branch and a statement. The kotlin is a null operatior (?), let, a block, a statement and whatever '$it' is.

Answer (score 4):

let takes the object it is invoked upon as the parameter and returns the result of the lambda expression.
Kotlin let is a scoping function wherein the variables declared inside the expression cannot be used outside.

One of the examples would be here :

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var str = "Hello World"
    str.let { println("$it!!") }
    println(str)

}
```

You can find more information on Kotlin let function [here](https://www.journaldev.com/19467/kotlin-let-run-also-apply-with#kotlin-let)