# Why is let used in null safe operations in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile

I've heard that let is used when you wish to perform a null safe operation on an Object by using the safe call operator `?.`.(according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58607101/12839666))
But the question is why this:

```
fun main() {
    var s: String? = null
    s = s?.let{ it.toUpperCase() }
    println(s)
}
```

is preferred over this:

```
fun main() {
    var s: String? = null
    s = s?.toUpperCase() 
    println(s)
}
```

In my opinion the 2nd variant is easier to read and understand which makes **let** useless.

So what is the purpose of **let** function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`?.let()` **is not** preferred over simple `?.toUpperCase()`. But we can't always use the latter, most importantly, we very often need to invoke a function of another object:

```kotlin
s?.let { parse(it) }
file?.let { FileInputStream(it) }
```

In addition, I personally sometimes prefer `?.let()` if there is a long chain of calls and null exists only at its beginning. I feel `?.let()` is then better for code clarity:

```kotlin
post?.let { it.author.personalInfo.address.street }
```

Instead of:

```kotlin
post?.author?.personalInfo?.address?.street
```